# Running into issues trying to locate previously saved Azure Spatial Anchors on iOS

Tags: azure-spatial-anchors

Trying to load previously saved Azure Spatial Anchors into an iOS app for use with indoor wayfinding. Have tried various approaches, including specifying the identifiers needed in the **ASAAnchorLocateCriteria** used to create the watcher. Anchors always come back with **ASALocateAnchorStatusNotLocated**.

This is in a simple iOS 12 app using ARKit with a SceneView. Upon display of the SceneView, we prompt the user to move the phone around until the **ASACloudSpatialAnchorSession** has enough info about the scene to determine the neighborhood ID.

In attempting to find anchors that have been previously saved in the same neighborhood ID using various approaches for criteria, nothing seems to make a difference. The anchors are not located.

```swift
let criteria = ASAAnchorLocateCriteria()!
criteria.identifiers = ["xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx"]
cloudSession!.createWatcher(criteria)
isLookingForNearbyAnchors = true
```

I'm looking to have the *sessionUpdated* event associated with our **ASACloudSpatialAnchorSession** fired with a status of **ASALocateAnchorStatusLocated** so we can then display the previously stored anchor in the scene.

Can anyone provide some insight into what I'm doing wrong here, or if this approach is possible with the current Azure Spatial Anchors SDK for iOS?

Comment: When looking up the anchors are you passing the anchor ID?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your issue?

Comment: @AlbertoVega-MSFT To answer your questions, yes, when looking up the anchors I am passing in the anchor identifier in the identifiers array on the ASAAnchorLocateCriteria for the session's watcher. In the code sample above, the "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx" represents the anchor ID. And no, I have not been able to resolve the issue. The anchors always come back ASAAnchorLocatedEventArgs.notLocated.

Comment: This will require some deeper analysis. Can you please file a support request @ https://aka.ms/azsupt? If you do not have access to a support plan, please reach out @ AZCommunity@microsoft.com with a link to this thread as well as your subscription ID and we can help get the support ticket opened for this issue.